# Message - Item already in cart (commerce)

Tags: commerce

I want to disable the ability of adding a product twice to the shopping cart.

Is there a way to prevent or prompt a message when a user tries to add the same product twice?

Comment: Did you already look at the proposed solutions here? https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/673/restrict-qty

Comment: Hi! Thanks I got it working after some adjustsments : )! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORMID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $product_ids = mymodule_get_products_in_cart();

  $line_item = $form_state['line_item'];
  $product = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['product_id']);
  if ($product->type == 'program') {
    if (in_array($product->product_id, $product_ids)) {
      // Product is already in cart! We only want to allow a quantity of 1,
      // so disable the submit button and change its text accordingly
      $form['submit']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
      $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Already in cart');
    }
  }
}   

/**
 * Return the product_id values for all products in the cart
 *
 * @return
 *  An array of product ids
 */
function mymodule_get_products_in_cart() {
  $product_ids = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);

  if (!isset($product_ids)) {
    global $user;
    $product_ids = array();
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
    if ($order) {
      $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
      foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
        $product_wrapper = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product;
        $product_ids[] = $product_wrapper->product_id->value();
      }
    }
  }

  return array_unique($product_ids);
}
?>
```

Comment: There is an issue with the last for each, I get an unexpected error

Comment: If you add shipping to your checkout, you'll get unexpected error; Change code by adding this inside your for each: if (in_array($line_item_wrapper->getBundle(), commerce_product_line_item_types())) {

Answer (score 0):

Checkout #5 of the following link - it shows how to do it if you have the stock module activated and disables the add to cart button.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1658788

Quote:

The commerce-stock add the event : "Check if a product add to cart form should be enabled" which is exactly what we want to do.

I added 2 conditions inside an "AND" condition set:

1. Data comparison (to check if the product page is of a product type B) : Parameter: Data to compare: [commerce-product:type], Data value: Product B
2. "Order contains products of particular product types" and select your other product type.

And then the magic comes from the action : "Advanced configuration of the add to cart form", also added by the commerce-stock module. With the following parameters : Parameter: Hide the Quantity field if it is visible: true, The text to set the action to: not compatible with..., Add a class to the add to cart form: no-eshop, Disable the add to cart?: true, Clear the submit array first: false, Clear the validation array first: false

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a bug. if you tried to add the same item to the cart more than once it will increment the item count instead of adding a duplicate item.